# Find the exact coordinates of all possible points D on the line through A and B so that D is four times as far from A as it (D) is from B

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, 3d

A(4, 7, -3)
B(-3, 1, 2) 
AB <-7, -6, 5>

parametric equation for AB: x = 4 - 7t ; y = 7 - 6t ; z = -3 + 5t

I tried to use the distance formula where I set 4d (d being the distance of D to B) as the distance from D to A. I really don't know where to a) go from there because I got stuck or b) begin.

The question says "exact coordinates" so I would assume there are multiple coordinates that fit the criteria. I guess this means I'd have to make/find a general equation to find all the points but I don't know where to start on that either.

Comment: In your title, you have “... as it ($D$) is from $D$.” Presumably, that last $D$ is meant to be a $B$.

Comment: Can you write down a parametric equation for the line?

Comment: @amd yes, I know how to write the parametric equation if that's what you're asking. I edited the question to include the parametric equation

Comment: In that case you’re almost done. Work out the distances to $A$ and $B$, set up the equation that expresses the distance constraint, and solve for $t$.

Comment: that doesn't make sense

Comment: The parametric equation describes a generic point $D=(4-7t,7-6t,-3+5t)$ on the line. Find those values of $t$ for which the distances $AD$ and $BD$ are in the correct proportion.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

what is the point in
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
x\\y\\z
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
4\\7\\-3
\end{pmatrix}
+t\begin{pmatrix}
-7\\-6\\5
\end{pmatrix}
$$
for $t=\frac{4}{5}$ ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a formula in coordinate geometry to find the coordinates of a point between 2 points $(x_1, y_1, z_1) and (x_2, y_2, z_3)$ in the ratio of m:n.

$$x = \frac{nx_1+mx_2}{m+n}$$
$$y = \frac{ny_1+my_2}{m+n}$$
$$z = \frac{nz_1+mz_2}{m+n}$$

There are 2 cases

Case 1 : D is between A and B
Apply the above formula we have D equals $(\frac{-8}{5}, \frac{11}{5}, 1)$

Case 2 : D is closer to B on AB's extension, then treat B as the middle point and AB:BD = 3:1.  We have
$\frac{3x+4}{4} = -3$    $x=\frac{-16}{3}$

Similarly y=-1 and z=11/3.